# Image loop - reloop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is being random at specific time within a range. I am having trouble relooping my function or reverts the counter back to one so it continue looping after the range.

Here is my code:

```
var i = 1;
function imgLoop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var rand = makeUniqueRandom();
        j = rand;
        img4 = '<div id="deck" class="center" >'
        img4 += '<img class="img_deck" src="http://example.com/images/' + j + '.jpg" />';
        img4 += '</div">'
        $(img4).hide().appendTo("#img_brd").fadeIn('slow');
        i++;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (i < 30) {
                $("#img_deck_border").remove().toArray();
                imgLoop();
            }
        }, 2000)

    }, 100)
}

imgLoop();
```

I tried passing parameter to `imgLoop()` as `imgLoop(i)` then `imgLoop(1)` but outputs wrong and doubles the appending of images. Thank you for helping.

Comment: If you want this to keep looping "after the range", why not just remove the `i < 30` check?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is your code without "image" part. What's wrong with it? http://jsfiddle.net/JbBwW/ If you want to reset the counter after the function completed, you have to do it somewhere and call your imgLoop again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbBwW/1/). This is your code without images, it just shows how you can change the amount of iterations of your loop. Hope it will help you.

```
var i = 1;
var amount = 30;
var isRunning = false;
function imgLoop() {
    isRunning = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        // here should be your work with images
        $("#output").text($("#output").text() + " " + i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (i < amount) {
                imgLoop();
            }
            else {
                isRunning = false;
                alert("I'm done");
            }
        }, 200)

    }, 100)
}

function addIterations() {
    amount += 10;
    if (!isRunning)
        imgLoop();
}

function start() {
    $("#div-start").remove();
    imgLoop();
}

$("#div-start").on("click", start);
$("#div-add").on("click", addIterations);
```